# Format all model & service URLs to include .json in AngularJS

Tags: json, rest, angularjs

I'm having a problem where my web service expects all RESTful urls to include a `.json` extension on the URL. I've made it so in my AngularJS code so that all URLs have that extension. So my service urls look like this:

```
/resources/:id.json
```

But the problem is that when I include the .json extension then the POST `create` restful action ends up posting to a URL that looks like:

```
/resources/.json
```

This throws an error.

What I need to do is set the defaults inside my AngularJS app to set .json just before each URL is returned. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this doesn't exist (yet) in AngularJS I had to fork a repo and add it myself.

Here's the repo with this feature added.

https://github.com/yearofmoo/angular.js

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

You could edit your copy of angular-resource.js to have this.  Accept a `suffix` parameter in your resource or something.